# R: Convert column with mixed 5-digits and character to date

Tags: r, excel, date

I read in an excel file which contains a column *date of death* that contains both date and strings. It looked fine in the excel, but when it is read into R, all of the dates got converted into 5 digits - looking something like this:

```
#>  date of death  
#>   <chr>           
#> 1 44673         
#> 2 44674         
#> 3 alive
#> 4 not known
#> 5 NA
```

Is there a way where

1. I could read in the excel file in a way that it doesn't get converted to the 5 digits?
2. If 1 is not possible, is there a way to convert that column into dates but for the numbers only?

Comment: Can you try `library(readxl);df1 <- read_excel(yourfile, col_types = "date")` or `col_types = "text"` if there are string values in the column

Comment: What do the strings in the column represent? Could you perhaps split the column in the Excel sheet itself on space or other delimiter since you have the date and the string in the same cell?

Comment: When reading excel, you should use the na argument of `read_excel()` . `read_excel("file.xlsx", na = c("NA", ".", "not known", "")`. usually, it well help R guess.

Comment: @akrun: this column is one of many columns (and other columns are of other classes) is there a way to set col_types for only one column?

Comment: @ltong you can pass a vector of types i.e. `col_types = c("date", "text", "numeric", ...)`

Comment: @akrun: I tried to set the col_types = "date" but it turned all of the strings in that column into NA

Comment: Can you try the conversion after reading then?  i.e. `df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(`date of death` = coalesce(as.character(janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(`date of death`))), `date of death`))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to keep the string as is, then we may convert to `Date` class on the numeric elements after reading and then `coalesce` with  the original column.  Note that column can have only a single type, so we may need to return as `character` type as there are strings

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
    mutate(`date of death` = coalesce(as.character(janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(
          as.numeric(`date of death`))), `date of death`))
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  `date of death`  col2
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 2022-04-22          5
2 2022-04-23          3
3 alive               9
4 not known          10
5 NA                 11
```

---

Tried with `read.xlsx` (from `openxlsx`) and `read_excel` (from `readxl`).  Based on the example created, `read_excel` does convert to `Date` class when specified the `col_types`, but that will also result in `NA` for the other string values in the same column.  However, `read.xlsx` with `detectDates` does the conversion

```
library(openxlsx)
df1 <- read.xlsx(file.choose(),  detectDates = TRUE)
df1
  date.of.death col2
1 2022-04-22      5
2 2022-04-23      3
3      alive      9
4   not known    10
5        <NA>    11

> sapply(df1, class)
date.of.death          col2 
  "character"     "numeric"
```

To keep the spaces in the column names, we may need to specify the `check.names` and the `sep.names`

```
df1 <- read.xlsx(file.choose(),  detectDates = TRUE,
      check.names = FALSE, sep.names = " ")
```